# Can I omit "A.D" when referring to a year, for example, "In 132" or "In 132 A.D."?

Tags: word-usage

I am not sure about the use of A.D. In some English references, I found it will be omitted sometimes(quite randomly). So I wonder if there is any principal use. Thank you.

Comment: This is really a style manual issue.  The designations of eras are used when necessary and vary--e.g., BC, AD; BCE, CE.  The Chicago Manual of Style now likes caps, no periods, but small caps with periods are acceptable.  But AD comes before the year, if used.

Comment: Please provide at least two concrete examples where you think the author left out AD for no justifiable reason ("quite randomly"). It was those incidents that prompted you to ask the question in the first place, so let us judge whether the omission is appropriate or misguided

Answer (score 4):

It is only necessary when leaving it out would cause confusion.
eg some minor battle in 132 then you probably need to specify AD/BC but if you said World War II started in 1939 then it is probably obvious enough.

ps In America (at least in academic works) it is probably better to use CE/BCE - although this is less common in everyday English.

Comment: As a possible rule of thumb, you might "need" (find it helpful) to use AD/BC/CE/BCE when talking of dates +/-500 years or so from "zero" (number plucked from air, but "feels about right"). Another possibility might be to use a suffix for any 3-digit year.